# postgres cannot create cluster as root?

Tags: postgresql

So I'm having trouble creating a data cluster in postgresql on an external drive with `pg_createcluster`. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and my user has `rwx` right on this folder, but still I got a permission error.

Here is the command I ran:

```
yuqiong@yuqiong-G7-7588:/media/yuqiong/DATA$ sudo pg_createcluster -u yuqiong -d /media/yuqiong/DATA/postgresdb --start 11 3dcitydb

Creating new PostgreSQL cluster 11/3dcitydb ...
/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/initdb -D /media/yuqiong/DATA/postgresdb --auth-local peer --auth-host md5
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "yuqiong".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /media/yuqiong/DATA/postgresdb ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 20
selecting default shared_buffers ... 400kB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... 2018-12-28 12:02:56.494 EST [405] FATAL:  data directory "/media/yuqiong/DATA/postgresdb" has invalid permissions
2018-12-28 12:02:56.494 EST [405] DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700) or u=rwx,g=rx (0750).
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/media/yuqiong/DATA/postgresdb"
Error: initdb failed
```

Here is my permission on that folder:

```
yuqiong@yuqiong-G7-7588:/media/yuqiong/DATA$ ll | grep postgresdb
drwxrwxrwx  1 yuqiong yuqiong      48 Dec 28 12:02 postgresdb/
```

I also tried `sudo chmod  0700 -R /media/yuqiong/DATA/postgresdb`, but this does not work either.

A caveat is my laptop has dual system of Windows and Ubuntu. This is originally a Windows laptop so the file system partition is `fuseblk` on this disk. Will this be a problem?

Another possibility is I read on the documentation that a cluster cannot be owned by `root`, but I'm not `root`? Also this does not seem to be what the error message suggests...

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a user `postgres` (or similar)  on your system? If yes try to use this account.

Comment: Did you try to mount the drive with other permissions?

Comment: @stickybit Yes there is. but `postgres` cannot own the folder on this particular drive because this drive's file system is not a linux partition, so I tried `chown` many times with no avail. Then I had to create a database user with this system account `yuqiong` because it's the directory owner.

Comment: @clamp thanks for the advice. this seems the only remaining solution now, except for changing computers. I'll try as I found some advice here https://askubuntu.com/questions/14863/how-to-auto-mount-a-flash-drive-with-root-and-read-write-execute-privileges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is my `/media/data` directory is a mounted hard disk formatted as Windows File System but not Linux one. Thus, the `chmod` and `chown` won't work. I eventually backed up everything and reformat the disk, which solved the problem.